# Check if layout is empty android studio

Tags: android, layout

I search a solution to check if my layout is empty

I click on a button if the layout is not empty I remove all view, but if he is empty he add some views

```
chapitre1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if (LAYOUT storyPart1 IS NOT EMPTY) {
                storyPart1.removeAllViews();

            } else {

                storyPart1.addView(story1_2);
                storyPart1.addView(story1_3);
                storyPart1.addView(story1_4);
                    storyPart1.addView(story2_1);
}
```

I search on internet but I don't find a solution :/
If someones have an idea :) ?

Regards

Comment: You can use `if (storyPart1.getChildCount() > 0)` (I'm assuming that storyPart1 is a ViewGroup or subclasses ViewGroup)

Comment: Thanks it perfectly what I needed :) thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Use `storyPart1.getChildCount() > 0`:

```
chapitre1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (storyPart1.getChildCount() > 0) {
            storyPart1.removeAllViews();
        } else {
            storyPart1.addView(story1_2);
            storyPart1.addView(story1_3);
            storyPart1.addView(story1_4);
            storyPart1.addView(story2_1);
        }
    }
}
```